# Customize macOS menu as Apple do with the Mac AppStore updates notifications

Tags: swift, macos, menu, submenu

How can I code a graphical view as appearing at the right of "App Store..." in the Apple menu (when updates are available in this example) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use NSView for such a special case.

See [Views in Menu Items - Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html) in the archived documentation for more info.